# URL lint tool no longer refreshes Facebook cache

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, caching

I am trying to use the Facebook URL lint tool, which normally clears the Facebook cache of a particular page, on this URL:

http://kasamaproject.org/threads/entry/dare-to-win-communists-can-think-big

But the tool no longer seems to have any effect on cached pages. Did Facebook change it? Is there an alternative method?

I also tried http://kasamaproject.org/threads/entry/dare-to-win-communists-can-think-big?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING in the Lint tool.

But no dice with that either.